# NextAuth csrfToken from REST API does not match csrfToken in request headers

Tags: node.js, next.js, csrf, next-auth

On my page, I am obtaining a csrfToken from NextAuth's `getCsrToken` (see https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/client#getcsrftoken) and this value is included in a hidden form field named `csrfToken`:

`page.tsx`

```
import { getCsrfToken } from "next-auth/react";

export default async function Page () {
  const csrfToken = await getCsrfToken();
  
  return (
    <form method="post" action="/api/auth/signup">
      <input type="hidden" name="csrfToken" value={csrfToken} />
      <input type="submit" value="Signup" />
    </form>
  )
}
```

I have an API route that the form posts to which calls NextAuth's `getCsrfToken` on the request headers in order to compare it with the csrfToken in the formData:

`route.ts`

```
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";
import { getCsrfToken } from "next-auth/react";

const handler = async function(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse
) {
  try {
    switch (req.method) {
      case "POST": {
        const csrfTokenFromReq = await getCsrfToken({ req: { headers: req.headers } });

        const formData = await req.formData();
        const csrfTokenFromBody = formData.get("csrfToken");

        ...
```

These two don't match, and `csrfTokenFromReq` changes with each request. I'm assuming this is a hash value? If so, what is the best way to go about comparing these values? Furthermore, is there a better way of securing against csrf with custom routes and NextAuth's built-in csrf functionality?

Also, these values are different than what I get from the REST API endpoint `/api/auth/csrf` (see https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/rest-api#get-apiauthcsrf).